# C#: Add objects into List<T> class dynamically

Tags: c#, list

I want to add all my objects into an List dynamically, without any hard coding.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Item objA = new Item();
        Item objB = new Item();
        int count = Item.getCount();// count = 2

        List<Item> cont1 = new List<Item>();
        while (count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                cont1.Add();
                //I missing an instance to get the objA and objB into cont1
                //I dont want hard code it, e.g: cont1.Add(objA).
            }

        }
   }
```

Comment: remove both lines `Item objX = new Item();', remove WHILE loop completely, leave just FOR loop and change the FOR's body to `cont1.Add(new Item());`

Comment: @SonerGönül: he doesn't want to probably because it would add the same object N times, while "objA, objB" suggests that he wants several different objects

Comment: Do not really understand the question ... Where are the objects that you want in your dynamic list?

Comment: Meaning that, if statically and if i have objA, objB, objC until objZ, i have to type cont1.Add(objA) until cont1.Add(objZ)...I want use for loop to add them into the list<T> without hard code them. Btw, does my question confuses you guys? why so many - votes for my question?

Comment: Because your question is very chaotic and while we can guess what you had on your mind - we should not need to. There are many small bits inside your queation that are vague. For example: you wrote "Main(){ Item objA=new Item() ..}" and now you say "statically". The 'objA, objB' variables in your code example are not static. They are local. Or, you have "new Item(), new Item()" and a "Item.getCount()" with comment "//count==2". What does this method actually count and how? We can guess, but you should say it. Then, inside For loop you have comment: "an instance to get" - again we can guess..

Comment: Sorry for confusing you all~~ And sorry for my poor knowledge on C# Programming Language. And sorry for my poor English, that why make you all confused with 'Statically' or 'dynamically'...LOL....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basing on your comment:

If you create 'static Item objA = new Item()' several times so that you end up with:

```
static Item objA = new Item();
static Item objB = new Item();
....
static Item objZ = new Item();
```

then to put them all into a list you **almost** have no other way than:

```
list = new List<Item>;
list.Add(objA);
list.Add(objB);
...
list.Add(objZ);
```

This is because you have already created the items, and already put them into several dozens of different variables and to put them into the list you simply have to tell the compiler **where it should get them from**. This means, that you have to tell him to get it from objA variable, and from objB variable and (...) and so on. This is because you have them in different variables.

The point is that you should chosen wrong way at the very beginning. You should never have created "objA, objB, objC, ...., objZ" in the first place. It should be a list or array or Dictionary or whatever collection, so that you can access all items at once easily. They should not been put into separate variables.

If you can, don't create that may variables. For example, use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Item> items = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
items["A"] = new Item();
items["B"] = new Item();
...
items["Z"] = new Item();
```

now, you can an item easily:

```
items["F"].Something = 321;
items["O"].Something = 123;
```

and you can access **all items** also as easily:

```
var number = items.Values.Count;

itemList = new List<Item>( items.Values );
```

Of course, sometimes you just don't have such option. For example, WinForms Designer creates variables for you and if you put 100 labels onto the Form, you will almost always end up having a 100 variables (although never static).

Nevertheless, all those variables will sit in some class. If your project setup allows you to use Reflection, then you can inspect that class and obtain a list of Names/Properties, and you can read their values:

```
class X
{
    public static Item objA = new Item();
    ..., objB, objC, ..... ,.....,
}

...

List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
foreach (var field in typeof(ListaUczniow).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
    if (field.Name.StartsWith("obj") && field.FieldType == typeof(Item))
        items.Add( (Item) field.GetValue(null) );
```

This may work for you, but in general, this is a very fragile approach: you have to watch out for proper BindingFlags, proper field names, proper field types, and the compiler cannot check the cast to Item automatically and even some security problems may arise if you write i.e. on Silverlight and your fields are private.

Answer (score 4):

```
int count = Item.getCount();// count = 2
```

looks to me as if your Item class increases a counter "under the hood" when the constructor is called and you want to access each instance of this class in your loop?

If so, your best bet seems to add the List directly as a (private) static property to the Item class itself and have the constructor do Add(this) to this list. Exposing it could then be done through a static `ReadOnlyCollection<Item>` collection.

Comment: +1: Indeed! Twice "new Item" and the comment "//getCount==2" really suggests that the author has some repository-like pattern hidden underneath. But, I wonder, isn't it currently somewhat too advanced? two loops and 'Add' problem looks like very early attempts